# Most Secure Bitcoin Node Motherboard to avoid IME & PSP?

Tags: full-node, electrum-server

What is the correct motherboard model / CPU type to choose if your goal is to build a secure Bitcoin Node that has none of the exploit compromised back doors listed below by CPU type:

1. Intel Management Engine (IME)/AMT/Vpro. Best motherboard model and manufacture date / CPU generation to choose to avoid IME?
2. AMD Platform Security Processor (PSP). Best motherboard model and manufacture date / CPU generation to choose to avoid PSP?

Additionally, is installing Coreboot or Libreboot the correct approach to disabling IME and PSP if the goal is to use a secure motherboard on which to build a Bitcoin node on top? Has anybody out there flashed either one and if yes what motherboard model was it done on?